# Usando Dompdf y no logro que utilice css

Tags: css, laravel-8, blade, dompdf

estoy usando dompdf para generar un pdf a partir de una vista en laravel 8 y si bien, logro hacer una primer prueba, es decir tengo la vista creada con un simple texto que sale en la generación del pdf, pero no logro hacer que tome el estilo css que pretendo aplicar, en el ejemplo estoy usando un css embebido en el html (entiendo que esto no es una buena práctica, pero lo estoy utilizando SOLO en modo experimental). A continuación les copio el código que estoy usando a ver si me pueden orientar para resolver esto.

Este es mi controller

```
public function ExportPDF($idCotizacion){
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('Cotizaciones.cotizPDF');
    return $pdf->stream('archivo.pdf');

}
```

Aquí pego el route

```
Route::get('cotizacion/{id}/expoPDF', [CotizacionController::class, 'ExportPDF'] )->name('Cotizaciones.ExportPDF');
```

aquí va la vista que debería generar el pdf

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>
        .titulo{
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: "Arial Narrow";
            color: green;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Export PDF</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="titulo">COTIZACIONES</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Con esto, estoy obteniendo el pdf con la palabra COTIZACIONES centrada, el tamaño del texto lo está tomando bien, también el color, pero no así con el tipo de letra.

Bueno, espero me puedan ayudar, saludos y muchas gracias.